# Basic question on associated primes.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q} \in \mathrm{Ass}(M)$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\subsetneq \mathfrak{q}$. Does there always exist $\mathfrak{p}'\in \mathrm{Ass}(M)$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\subsetneq \mathfrak{p}'\subset\mathfrak{q}$ and $\mathrm{height}(\mathfrak{p}')=\mathrm{height}(\mathfrak{p})+1$? Assume that the ring is Noetherian or that the module is finitely generated if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $R=k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/(x_1^2, x_1x_2,\ldots, x_1x_n)$ and $M=R$.

Comment: Did you mean $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ to be $(x_1)$ and $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ respectively?

Comment: @Jehu314 Yes. Since $n$ can be arbitrary.